# Ending summation with "and" right before another "and"?

Tags: word-choice

Let's say I have this sentence:

> This process uses *[summation]* and produces *z*.

Should it be written like this:

> This process uses *w*, *x* and *y* and produces *z*.

Or like this?

> This process uses *w*, *x*, *y* and produces *z*.

Comment: How about this one: _This process uses w, x, and y to produce z_. That would eliminate the awkward and-and construct that troubles you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter example doesn't make sense:

> This process uses w, x, y[,] **and** produces z.

This looks like it contains a four-element list, but it can't; the reader will quickly see that *produces z* can't possibly combine with *this process uses*, so they'll instead interpret "w, x, y" as an asyndetic three-element list.  ("Asyndetic" means lacking an overt coordinator such as *and*.)

Unfortunately, in this context asyndetic coordination is strange, and it may confuse some readers.  The combination of two *and*s is better:

> This process uses w, x[,] **and** y **and** produces z.

The first *and* signals to the reader that the following element *y* completes the list.  This allows the reader to unambiguously interpret *and produces z* as separate from the list.

(I've placed the optional serial comma in square brackets.  It doesn't make a difference here.)

Of course, as J.R. and gelolopez point out, you don't have to write either of these sentences.  You can avoid a perceived problem by writing a different sentence, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you use all w,x,and y to produce z, some standards dictate that you should use

> ...uses w,x,and y, and produces z.

This is called serial comma or an Oxford Comma.

But in order to avoid any confusion, I suggest you write your sentence like this:

> This process uses w,x, and y, which produces z.